# fat-free framework flush partial output

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm writing some back-office web pages for maintenance of our systems.
I'm using F3
I have one route with a long processing, divided in many subprocesses.
I made one template per subprocess, this way:

```
$f3->route('GET /someroute', function($f3) {
   dosomework();
   echo template::instance()->render('template-job1.html');

   dosomeotherwork();
   echo template::instance()->render('template-job2.html');
}
```

I would like that i get in browser partial output as it is ready (one template at time) but what i get it is i have to wait for all the output.

If i try with a standard php output (e.g. with some sleep() and some echo()) I get line by line and not all together at the end of process.

Another example with f3:

```
$f3->route('GET /output', function($f3) {
    echo "pippo\n";

    for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
        echo ".";
        sleep(1);
    }
});
```

Does output after 100s. Instead if I write a simple php page:

```
<?php
echo "pippo2\n";

    for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
        echo ".";
        sleep(1);
    }
```

It outputs a dot every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the framework stores the complete response before sending it to the client, using PHP's [output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

So you should first disable the output buffer and turn on implicit output flush:

```
$f3->route('GET /output', function($f3) {

    // disable output buffering
    while (ob_get_level())
        ob_end_flush();

    // turn implicit flush
    ob_implicit_flush(1);

    // now every output call should be flushed instantly to the client
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        echo $i;
        sleep(1);
    }

});
```

NB1: disabling output buffering will prevent the framework from populating the [RESPONSE](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/quick-reference#RESPONSE) variable.

NB2: some browsers may themselves buffer the received output, i.e wait a minimum amount of data before displaying it. See [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) for details.