# Flushing response headers and body in Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

In Fat Free Framework, is it possible to return HTTP headers and body (generated via template) to the browser before the end of a controller method? Looking for something akin to PHP's builtin `flush()` function. I want to return the response to the browser such that it doesn't expect any more data, and then run code that may take a long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fat-free framework flush partial output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177425/fat-free-framework-flush-partial-output)

Comment: also worth trying is `$f3->abort()`, see https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#abort

Comment: @ikkez abort() worked on Linux, but not on Windows due to not using fastcgi. Can you post your response as an answer so I can approve?

Comment: thanks.. yes it's only for fastcgi, but apache can be configured using fastcgi and nginx is using it by default, isn't it? You can also check out a little workaround wrapper I built, see [SimpleThread](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/SimpleThread) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [fat-free framework flush partial output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177425/fat-free-framework-flush-partial-output)﻿, so see there for some solutions. Also worth trying is the `$f3->abort()` feature, see https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#abort